# How to round float numbers with custom Ceil Floor condition

Tags: javascript, math, numbers, ceil

Is there any builtin function exist ? or can you please give a solution for that.

I need the numbers to show as like this:

> ```
> 169.4 => 170
> 193.6 => 194
> 171.51050 => 172
> 367.35000000000003 => 367
> ```

My condition is if the first number after the point is greater then or equal to 4 then it will be Ceil otherwise floor.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round

Comment: `function con(val) {
  val += 0.10;
  return Math.round(val)
}

console.log(con(169.4))
console.log(con(193.6))
console.log(con(171.51050))
console.log(con(367.45000000000003))`

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for rounding

```
Math.round(number);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Math.round`

```js
function con(val) {
  return Math.round(val)

}

console.log(con(169.4))
console.log(con(193.6))
console.log(con(171.51050))
console.log(con(367.45000000000003))
```

Comment: thanks. is there any condition that will also check if its greater or equal then 4 ?